# Referencing with svjour3 (Springer)

Tags: bibliographies, sv-classes

I am unable to do referencing with natbib using springer 's svjour3 template. If I add natbib in the following preamble, it gives me error. I wanna use *author year style for citation* and alphabetical references with my bib file.
what am I doing wrong?

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}  
\smartqed 
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\clearpage
\begin{document}
```

Comment: You can use `natbib` as a global option and kick ouy both packages, natbib and cite, from the preamble. Harder to say more, since 8gives me error* isn't specific. please provide a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html0.

Comment: For sure, do not load both `cite` and `natbib`.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thank you for response. kicking out both cite and natbib does not solve my issue. If I add only \usepackage{natbib}, it does not solve my problem. Excuse me I am very beginner, I dont know how to explain my problem in technological language as minimal working example.

Comment: It is no technological language, it is just a code example. A compilable one. Just take half an hour to read the linked material and we will be able to help you within minutes. Without understanding a problem, a solution will achieved by guessing and looking into a crystal ball for days. And that is very unsatisfying.

Comment: Maybe you just need to delete the auxiliary files. not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained above, keeping only `natbib` leads to something that works

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\smartqed

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@BOOK{foo,
  AUTHOR =       {J. Doe and F. Foo},
  address =      {London},
  TITLE =        {How to fix the problem?},
  PUBLISHER =    {Wiley},
  YEAR =         {2015},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
My beautiful document has the following reference \citet{foo}.
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

produces the following output:

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth, and in case someone else is losing sleep over this: `spbasic` works fine, but `spmpsci` yields the same errors.